# Mvvmcross 7 - How to allow the ViewModel to detect the Application is Closing

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, mvvmcross

In my WPF application using MvvmCross 7+, the MainWindow (`MvxWindow`) hosts the selected viewmodel (`MvxViewModel`) / view (`MvxWpfView`).  What I need is for that viewmodel to be able to be notified that the user has clicked the upper right close button on the application so I can trigger a data save down in the viewmodel.

I can of course wire up the `MvxWindow_Closing` event in the MainWindow, but how do you notify the viewmodel?  How does the MainWindow know what viewmodel is active?

Down in the viewmodel, I've implemented the `ViewDisappearing()` event but that event doesn't trigger when the application close button is pressed and the whole app is shut down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if Mvvmcross does anything special, but a view's view model is usually accessible via its `DataContext` property.

Comment: @Clemens  Yeah mvvmcross must do something different as the DataContext property is null on the MainWindow closing event.

Comment: ViewDestroy and ViewDisappearing should get called: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Wpf/Views/MvxWindow.cs#L62

Comment: @Cheesebaron

No joy...I took the TipCalc.Core and added both of those overrides to the viewmodel.   Neither of these overrides are triggered when the upper right window closes via the X button.